# Computation of matrix norms for p-norms.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am having a hard time with the following problem.

For a matrix $A\in \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$, we denote by
$$
||A||_{\infty\rightarrow 1,\mathbb{K}}=\max_{x\in \mathbb{K}^n\setminus \{0\}}\frac{||Ax||_1}{||x||_{\infty}}
$$
its matrix norm with respect to the infinity norm on $\mathbb{K}^n$ and the 1-norm on its codomain $\mathbb{K}^m$. Specifically, we consider the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which we can interpret either as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$.Compute the matrix norm $||A||_{\infty\rightarrow 1,\mathbb{R}}$ for the case $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$.

What I have so far; Let $x=(x_1,x_2)^T\in  \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$. We then have that
$$
Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1-x_2 \\ x_1+x_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
which gives
$$
||Ax||_1=|x_1-x_2|+|x_1+x_2|
$$
we also have that
$$
||x||_{\infty}=\sup\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}
$$
This gives
$$
||A||_{\infty\rightarrow 1,\mathbb{R}}=\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}}\frac{|x_1-x_2|+|x_1+x_2|}{\sup\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}}
$$
Not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: Isn't $\lVert x \rVert_\infty = \max\{\vert x_1 \vert, \vert x_2 \vert\}$ ?

Comment: You are of course correct, silly mistake. Still don't know what to do though.

Comment: **Hint:** Show that
$$
    \dfrac{\vert x_1 - x_2 \vert + \vert x_1 + x_2 \vert}{2} = \max\{\vert x_1 \vert, \vert x_2 \vert\}
$$